# upper.tri with array in R

Tags: r

I have a function which returns `300` arrays like this:

```
, , 38

          [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4] [,5]
[1,] 1.0000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000    1
[2,] 1.4457207 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000    1
[3,] 1.1491685 1.152171 1.000000 1.000000    1
[4,] 0.9009709 0.600254 1.444501 1.000000    1
[5,] 1.0620356 1.769513 1.147224 2.505219    1

, , 39

          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]     [,4] [,5]
[1,] 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.000000    1
[2,] 1.0693369 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.000000    1
[3,] 1.8235562 1.6199451 1.0000000 1.000000    1
[4,] 0.6631731 0.9665938 0.2569683 1.000000    1
[5,] 0.7608913 2.3203717 0.7305705 4.549893    1

, , 40

         [,1]      [,2]     [,3]     [,4] [,5]
[1,] 1.000000 1.0000000 1.000000 1.000000    1
[2,] 1.003870 1.0000000 1.000000 1.000000    1
[3,] 1.206578 0.8969491 1.000000 1.000000    1
[4,] 1.205347 1.2673170 1.345472 1.000000    1
[5,] 2.741506 2.0376783 1.151699 2.787262    1
```

I  would like to convert all the upper (including diagonal) to `0`.

```
lapply(x,function(x) x[,,][upper.tri(x[,,],diag = T)] <- 0)
```

but does not work. Any help please?

Comment: It is not clear from your question if you have a list with 300 arrays or an array with z dimension equal to 300. It is helpful to provide a little toy example of your data that represents your real data to clarify such situations.

Comment: I meant `300` arrays like in my example.

Comment: Your non-reproducible example is a single array with a z (third) dimension of at least 40. The `, , 40` in the print out verifies this. a list of forty matrices would print out with `[[40]]`.

Comment: As a note, an `upper.tri`-like functionality for 3d arrays could be achieved through `?slice.index` -- `slice.index(x, 1) <= slice.index(x, 2)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can simply use a `for` loop

```
for(i in seq(dim(x)[3])) x[,,i][upper.tri(x[,,i], diag = TRUE)] <- 0
```

giving

```
x
#, , 1

#           [,1]         [,2]       [,3]      [,4] [,5]
#[1,]  0.0000000  0.000000000  0.0000000 0.0000000    0
#[2,]  0.5365853  0.000000000  0.0000000 0.0000000    0
#[3,]  0.4196231 -0.466495124  0.0000000 0.0000000    0
#[4,] -0.5836272 -0.848370044 -1.4290903 0.0000000    0
#[5,]  0.8474600  0.002311942  0.3322444 0.5163357    0

#, , 2

#            [,1]      [,2]       [,3]       [,4] [,5]
#[1,]  0.00000000 0.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000    0
#[2,] -0.08554095 0.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000    0
#[3,]  0.11953107 0.6128514  0.0000000  0.0000000    0
#[4,] -0.11629639 1.5171225  0.1692267  0.0000000    0
#[5,] -0.94382724 0.6573804 -1.8221903 -0.2557446    0

#, , 3

#           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4] [,5]
#[1,]  0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000  0.000000    0
#[2,] -1.0736261 0.0000000 0.0000000  0.000000    0
#[3,]  0.7696819 1.1782477 0.0000000  0.000000    0
#[4,]  1.7709054 1.0494212 1.3185662  0.000000    0
#[5,] -0.1961822 0.5609812 0.5713866 -1.567617    0
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
x <- array(rnorm(5*5*3), dim = c(5, 5, 3))
```